# Split an array into data based on bins returned by numpy histogram

Tags: python, histogram, frequency, bins

I have an array `x` with data like this: [3.1, 3.0, 3.3, 3.5, 3.8, 3.75, 4.0] etc.
I have another variable `y` with corresponding 0s and 1s [0, 1, 0]
I want to get from that new separate arrays to have that divided

```
freq, bins = np.histogram(X, 5)
```

That allows me to know the cutoffs for each bin. But how do I actually get that data? For example, if I have two bins (3 to 3.5 and 3.5 to 4), I want two get two arrays in return like this [3.1, 3.2, 3.4, ...] and [3.6, 3.7, 4, ...]. Also, I want the variable `y` to be broken and sorted in the same fashion.

**Summary**: I am looking for code to break `x` into bins with corresponding `y` values.

I thought about doing something using the `bins` variable, but I am not sure how to split the data based on the cutoffs. I appreciate any help.

If I graph a normal histogram of X, I get this: [image]

Using code:

```
d=plt.hist(X, 5, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.5)
```

Working Code:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def getLists(a, b, bin_obj):
    index_list = []
    for left, right in pairwise(bin_obj):
        indices = np.where((a >= left) & (a < right))
        index_list += [indices[0]]
    X_ret = [a[i] for i in index_list]
    Y_ret = [b[i] for i in index_list]
    return (X_ret, Y_ret)
freq, bins = np.histogram(X[:, 0], 5)

Xnew, Ynew = getLists(X[:, 0], Y, bins)
```

Comment: Can there be any duplicate values in `x`?

Comment: Yes, X can be anything between 0 and 4, but is more likely to be between 3 and 4. Duplicate values can and will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handful python function [defined](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the standard library.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

It can help you to iterate through your bins and get the indices of your elements.

```
for left, right in pairwise(bins):
    indices = np.where((x >= left) & (x < right))
    print(x[indices], y[indices])
```

Comment: The print statement did not work because indices contain some other data other than the indexes. I put the working code in my question. Thanks!